# Does PHP 7 make easier to substitute comma operator?

Tags: php, php-7, comma-operator

I have learned so far that PHP lacks comma operator (I am not here for **opinions** if it is good or bad). Since I I fall into pattern of such expressions:

```
($tmp = bar(), foo($tmp), $tmp)
```

1. perform computation and cache the output
2. use the cached value (call a function with given value)
3. return the cached value

I can substitute the comma operator with calling a custom function which takes value and lambda, and returns the value.

But I wonder -- maybe PHP 7 brought some new feature that makes substitution easier or allows to substitute all forms of comma operator expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, but since PHP 7 you can easily create and call a lambda function at the same time, thanks to the new AST:

```
(function() { $tmp = bar(); foo($tmp); return $tmp; })();
```

Comment: In earlier versions this would do too: `call_user_func(function () { .. })`.

Comment: Thank you, it is more concise than I thought.